# Travis error on react-native IOS release scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, travis-ci

When i build ios release scheme locally i get no errors, but when i build on travis the release scheme i get this error under Running script 'Bundle React Native code and images':

File /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-bktrthrvpvtbhdcrrzrzfekixdcy/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/TestApp.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with

I checked that when i run it locally the main.jsbundle is copied inside this folder but on travis this file is not copied although before building i run:
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
This is my .travis.yml configuration:

`- language: objective-c
          sudo: required
          xcode_project: ios/TestApp.xcworkspace
          xcode_scheme: ios/Release
          node_js: false
          env:
            - TEST='IOS RELEASE BUILD'
          before_install:
            - nvm install 9.10.0
          install:
            - brew install yarn
            - yarn install
            - npm install -g react-native-cli
          script:
            - react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
            - cd ios
            - xcodebuild -workspace TestApp.xcworkspace -scheme Release -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty -c; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`

I am using react-native v0.56

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after searching i solved it by adding this line to my travis.yml

`nvm alias default v9.10.0`

after nvm install 9.10.0

Apparently, the script was using an other version of node and by setting this I forced it to use this node version